# Sonata Block - execute shows "Declaration must be compatible.."

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

Getting this error at "execute" method.

```
Declaration must be compatible with BlockServiceInterface->execute(blockContext : \Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface, [response : \Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Response = null])
```

my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "misd/guzzle-bundle": "^1.1",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.2",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.2"
```

My class, where this "execute" method is placed and getting the error:

```
<?php

namespace Socca\UserBundle\SonataController;

use Socca\UserBundle\Form\Type\UploadingFormType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BaseBlockService;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UploadingService extends BaseBlockService
{
    private $formFactory;

    public function getName()
    {
       return 'uploading';
    }

    public function execute(BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Response $response = null)
    {
        $block = $blockContext->getBlock();
        $form = $this->getFormFactory()->createBuilder(new UploadingFormType(), null)
            ->getForm();

        if (!$block->getEnabled()) {
            return new Response();
        }

        $settings = $blockContext->getSettings();
        $resolver = new OptionsResolver();
        $resolver->setDefaults($settings);
        $settings = $resolver->resolve($block->getSettings());

        return $this->renderResponse('SoccaUserBundle:Block:uploading.html.twig', array(
            'block'     => $blockContext->getBlock(),
            'settings'  => $settings,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ), $response);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFormFactory()
    {
        return $this->formFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $formFactory
     */
    public function setFormFactory($formFactory)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }
}
```

If i check the `BaseBlockService` class of `namespace Sonata\BlockBundle\Block`, it is full of "wrong" methods saying the same "Declaration must be compatible...".
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`by `use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Response`

Comment: This class does not exist.

Comment: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle/tree/master/Block there is no such file

Comment: and `BaseBlockService` itself uses Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; there is something wrong about that, strange message of nonexisting class requirements.

Comment: Have you tried with an '\' before? Like `use \Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Response`

Comment: Ok forgot my comment, the class doesn't exists as @mansim said.